# cvGetCol throwing "OpenCV: Unrecognized or unsupported array type"

Tags: c#, emgucv, opencv3.1

I'm trying to manipulate individual columns using OpenCV3 (Emgu) in c#.  I have code that is similar to:

```
UMat Image = loaded image
UMat Column = new UMat();

CvInvoke.cvGetCol(Image, Column, 1);
```

**{"OpenCV: Unrecognized or unsupported array type"}**

And that is throwing the error in the header. I have tried `Mat` and `Mat.Ptr` instead of `UMat`, but nothing helps. While I have found 1-2 c++ examples, I cannot find a c# example to help.

Comment: Can you update your question with the error , that would help provide you the right advice.

Comment: Added the error in bold.

Answer (score 0):

While not the solution to this issue, I was able to get similar functionality using the Matrix<> type instead of UMats.

```
UMat Image = ...
Matrix<byte> ImageMatrix = new Matrix<byte>(Image.Rows, Image.Cols, 3);
Image.CopyTo(ImageMatrix);

ImageMatrix.GetCol(1);
```

I believe this will be slower than using the CvInvoke calls with UMat types, but it works while looking for a complete solution to the above issue.